# Can't get PHP variable through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using Wordpress and I have a page where I have a drop down that when the links are clicked it will make an Ajax call and pass the data variable to PHP, at least that is what I'm attempting to do lol.

When clicking on the link I check my browser and in the Network tab for the page I receive a variable for the data object in the html and the ajax post's to the php page but for some reason I can't get a value.

**My HTML**

```
<div class="category-submenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-office="Corporate">Corporate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-office="Office1">Office1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-office="Office2">Office2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-office="Office3">Office3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**My jQuery**

```
$('.category-submenu a').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/load-team.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {office: $(this).data('office')},
        success: function(data) {
            $.each( data, function(i, item) {
                alert(data[i].start);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**My PHP**

```
<?php

    $office = $_GET['office'];
    $link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("Could not connect");

    mysql_select_db("somedb") or die("Could not select database");

    $arr = array();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM ic_team_members WHERE office ='" . $office . "'");

    while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
        $arr[] = $obj;
    }

    echo '{"members":'.json_encode($arr).'}';

 ?>
```

I'm sure there is some code missing or my syntax might be incorrect in some parts but I can't seem to find where, if any place.

Again I want to grab the data object from HTML element, pass it through Ajax into PHP and return the result as json object, which I can do but for some reason I think the error is in my PHP.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hope your escaping before you are entering this into your query

Comment: Don't generate JSON on your own, use `json_encode(array("members"=>$arr))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing it by `POST`, and therefore you need to receive it with `POST`:

```
$office = $_POST['office'];
```

Otherwise, use GET to send the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    ...

});
```

Comment: Or if you're unsure of which type of submit is coming, you can use `$_REQUEST`!

Comment: Wow that was simple, thank you for the 2nd pair of eyes on something so silly

Comment: @RUJordan true. Bu this one should not be the case.

Comment: @RUJordan That's true, but you should know what type of submit is happening, that is, you should use GET for retrieving and POST for updating